# Use of REDIRECT in Helper file in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to integrate *REDIRECT* function into the Helper file in *Codeigniter 4*. But the redirect is not working. Below is the sample code -

Controller -

```
function update_project_details($projectId)
    {
        logged_in_admin();
.....
}
```

Helper -

```
if (!function_exists('logged_in_admin')) {
    function logged_in_admin() {
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        if ($session->get('admin_id') == '') {
            return redirect()->route('admin/signin');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting session value of 'admin_id' as blank so expected that the redirect functon should redirect my page. But it is not redirecting to specified route.

Comment: Try returning the _"Helper method"_ call. I.e: `return logged_in_admin();`

Comment: @Vickel Since the OP is using loosey equality comparison,  `null == ''` is truthy.

Comment: Why not use a filter for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I added the 'return' to the helper call in controller as suggested by @steven7mwesigwa, but the code was getting stuck when helper function returns nothing. So i modified in a way below -

Controller -

```
function update_project_details($projectId)
    {
        if(logged_in_admin() !== true){
            return logged_in_admin();
        }
.....
}
```

Helper -

```
if (!function_exists('logged_in_admin')) {
    function logged_in_admin() {
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        if ($session->get('admin_id') == '') {
            return redirect()->route('admin/signin');
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working. Thank you for suggestions and help.